# How to pass a variable to css in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, css

I'm trying to make a virtual scroll and whenever the user scrolls down I need to add a negative top **equal to the container height** to each row. But of course this top property can vary depending of some factors like the user's screen resolution or browser window size.

So far this is what I got:

```
  <div class="container" id="my-container">
  <!--If it has the class row-scrolled the top property is applied-->
      <div ng-repeat="(row) in virtualCollection"
       ng-class="{'row-scrolled': controller.isScrolled}">
         <!-- row properties -->
      </div>
  </div>
```

I have also thought about the idea of using ng-style but would override any style from my .css file.

Is there anyway to get the size/property of a DOM element...

```
// controller
var containerHeight = angular.element('#my-container')[0].clientHeight;
var cssProperty = '-' + containerHeight + 'px';
```

And then use it in an css?

```
// css
.row-scrolled {
  top: cssProperty;
}
```

Comment: Why would ng-style "override any style from your .css file."? Isn't that the expected result? Ng-style dynamically adding the expected calculated height to the element?

Comment: @SPArcheologist Well I am using material design and using ng-style would get rid of any style. I would have to insert in my ng-style every single property applied to that row. I forgot to say that in my question, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass variables from javascript to CSS *since [CSS is not a programming language but a style sheet language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).*

What you **can** do is manipulating specific elements with javascript.
Based on your code here is an example:

```
// controller
var containerHeight = angular.element('#my-container')[0].clientHeight;
var cssProperty = '-' + containerHeight + 'px';
var $$rowScrolled = document.querySelectorAll(".row-scrolled");

if ($$rowScrolled && $$rowScrolled.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $$rowScrolled.length; i++) {
        var $rowScrolled = $$rowScrolled[i];

        $rowScrolled.style.top = cssProperty;         
    }
}
```

---

*With jQuery*:

```
// controller
var containerHeight = angular.element('#my-container')[0].clientHeight;
var cssProperty = '-' + containerHeight + 'px';
var $rowScrolled = $(".row-scrolled");

if ($rowScrolled && $rowScrolled.length > 0) {
    $rowScrolled.css("top", cssProperty);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to not use a loop for such thing since I had problems re-rendering my virtual collection and adding changing css properties at the same time. Thank you very much.

Comment: Using jQuery would not require using a loop

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass a variable to the CSS.

What you can do though is add the property directly using the ng-style tag:

```
<div class="container" id="my-container">
  <!--If it has the class row-scrolled the top property is applied-->
  <div ng-repeat="(row) in virtualCollection"
   ng-style="{'top': controller.cssProperty}">
     <!-- row properties -->
  </div>
```

Comment: This answer is assuming that you can access the controllers properties using the 'controller' keyword. You might have to use $scope, or if it's a component '$ctrl' instead.