# Changing the color of input placeholder using ng-style

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have $scope variable in my controller to define the color of input placeholder that I want to embed in my html code.

The $scope variable defined as following:

```
$scope.primaryColor={"color":colorVar}; //colorVar is the color in hex
```

The color var has a dynamic value, and I would like to use ng-style on the input html tag to set the color property for the placeholder inside the input.

```
<input required name="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="hi@whatever.com" ng-style="">
```

I am aware that I cannot change the placeholder color property through inline css. Is there a way I can pass the color var to css using ng-style or any other methods?

How can I do that?

Comment: I think you will have to have a separate class per colour.

Comment: Classes will create limited colors only. Which I don't want to go this way. @RyanSearle

Comment: I ran through a similar issue a while ago, and I'm afreid you will have to use ng-class. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48438834/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-css-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Adding the ng-class to the vendor prefix does the trick

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Quick test" required="" 
class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched">
```

Scss:

```
.ng-touched::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: red; }
.ng-untouched::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #cccccc; }
```

Comment: This is a fixed color value. I want to pass the color from the $scope color variable.

Comment: Your answer is the right approach, but you need to apply it in AngularJS way.

Comment: you can define any name of variable like $color : anycolor and this $color you use in color : $color

Comment: @PPL I don't think it is possible to pass $scope to css like this. Maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a stylesheet dynamically? It may not be the most elegant, but it will work.

```
const sheet = document.createElement('style');
document.body.appendChild(sheet);
sheet.innerHTML = '.btn-primary {background-color: ' + colorVar  + '!important;}';
sheet.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'input::placeholder {color:' + colorVar + '!important;}');
```

You'll have to import your variables accordingly from the database or where ever you store the color codes, and you'll also have to determine the best place to put this code in your app, but this should get you going.

Comment: Great idea, but I couldn't change the placeholder color and insert the input using the above code